# Overleaf: "fontspec all the fonts!": LaTeX source?

Tags: overleaf, sourcecode

Is there a LaTeX source available for the following pdf?

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fontspec-all-the-fonts/hjrpnxhrrtxc

Or at least an old version? Or something similar (a document with many fonts together)?

Answer (score 2):

(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)

I'm afraid I won't make you happy. The source code for that doc is not available, as the doc currently exceeds some XeTeX's limitations -- the fonts are simply too many! Therefore the list is created with some hacky solutions that we're not planning on publishing, sorry for the limitation.

However, using the list we have at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F, you can quickly do something like this that lists all the serif fonts that are there (note that while they are available in Overleaf, you might not have some of them on your machine) (use XeLaTeX for this):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\title{Fontspec Serif fonts (2021 edition, Overleaf Support showcase)}
\author{Tom (Overleaf Support)}
\date{May 2022}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,vmargin={1cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\&=12

\foreach \x in {Aboriginal Serif, Abyssinica SIL, Accanthis ADF Std No3, Alegreya, Alfios, AlgolRevived, Annapurna SIL, Antykwa Poltawskiego, Antykwa Poltawskiego Light, Antykwa Torunska, Antykwa Torunska Condensed, Asea, Avdira, Averia Serif GWF, BABEL Unicode, Baskervald ADF Std, Baskervaldx, BaskervilleF, Berenis ADF Pro, Berenis ADF Pro SC, Berylium, Bitstream Vera Serif, Bookman Uralic, BPG Serif GPL&GNU, BPG Serif Modern GPL&GNU, C059, Caladea, Cardo, Caslon, Century Catalogue, Charis SIL, Charis SIL Compact, Cinzel, Cinzel Decorative, Clara, CMU Concrete, CMU Serif, CMU Serif Extra, CMU Serif Upright Italic, CMU Typewriter Text Variable Width, Cochineal, Coelacanth, Conakry, Cormorant Garamond, Credit River, Credit Valley, Crimson, Crimson Pro, DejaVu Serif, Domitian, Doulos SIL, Doulos SIL Compact, Droid Serif, Dustismo Roman, EB Garamond, Echelon Condensed, Eczar, Edmunds, Edmunds Distressed, Effloresce, Effloresce Antique, EMERITA Latina, Essays1743, ETbb, Ezra SIL, Ezra SIL SR, Fanwood, Fanwood Text, Foulis Greek, FreeSerif, Furat, Galatia SIL, Gayathri, Gentium, Gentium Basic, Gentium Book Basic, Gentium Plus, Gentium Plus Compact, GentiumAlt, Georgia, GFS Artemisia, GFS Bodoni, GFS Didot, Goodfish, Goudy Bookletter 1911, Heuristica, IBM Plex Serif, IM FELL DW Pica, IM FELL English, IM FELL English SC, IndUni-N, IndUni-P, IndUni-T, Inria Serif, Irianis ADF Std, Irianis ADF Style Std, Junicode, Kalpurush, KpRoman, Latin Modern Roman, Latin Modern Roman Dunhill, Liberation Serif, Libertinus Serif, Libre Baskerville, Libre Bodoni, Libre Caslon Text, Linden Hill, Linux Libertine Display O, Linux Libertine O, Mekanus ADF Std, Mekanus ADF Titling Std, Merriweather, Merriweather Light, MPH 2B Damase, NewComputerModern08, NewComputerModern10, Nimbus Roman, Noto Serif, NovelDeco, Old Standard TT, Oradano-mincho-GSRR, Palladio Uralic, Parix, Playfair Display, Prociono, PT Serif, QTAntiquePost, QTBasker, QTBengal, QTBodini, QTBookmann, QTCaslan, QTCaslanOpen, QTFrizQuad, QTGaromand, QTGraphLite, QTGraveure, QTKorrin, QTOldGoudy, QTPalatine, QTSchoolCentury, QTWeise, Quattrocento, Rasa, RIT-Sundar, Roboto Slab, Romande ADF No2 Std, Romande ADF Std, Romande ADF Style Std, Schoolbook Uralic, Soufflet Vert, Source Serif Pro, Spira, Subpear, Sweynheim & Pannartz, Symbola, Tempora, TeX Gyre Bonum, TeX Gyre Pagella, TeX Gyre PagellaX, TeX Gyre Schola, TeX Gyre ScholaX, TeX Gyre Termes, TeX Gyre TermesX, Times New Roman, Tinos, Tribun ADF Std, Tymes, URW Bookman, Vahika, Verana, Vollkorn, XCharter, Yrsa} {
    \subsection*{\x}
    \fontspec{\x}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\\
    Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works just as well with `LuaLaTeX` … Just saying.

Comment: Where is the limitation? Your document has 1262 fonts. I have experience with less fonts in the document: 379, see http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/op-catalog.pdf and it is still without problems with LuaTeX. My interest is, how many fonts can I add to this document without exceeding limitation.

Comment: Hi @wipet, I'm sorry but I don't know about LuaTeX's limitations, so I can't really give an answer, but you're free to ask a separate question for that :)

Comment: @Ingmar That's an interesting point that we might explore, thanks :)